# what is the difference between hibernate 2.X and hibernate 3.0

Tags: hibernate

can anybody explain me exact difference between hibernate 2.X and hibernate 3.0
i could not figure out the same

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Typically version increases include more features and bug fixes.  Here is the hibernate 2->3 migration guide, which should give you an idea.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide30

You'll see that they did things like make all exceptions unchecked, added some methods in places, deprecated some methods in places, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Some of Key Points Hibernate 2.x V Hibernate 3.x:

Hibernet2.x version increases to Hibernet3.x, that is include 
   more features and bug fixes.
   Hibernate 3.0 is not source-compatible with Hibernate 2.1.
   The changes made in Hibernet3.0 were carefully designed to 
   allow straightforward migration of both code and metadata.
   It is possible to run Hibernate 2.x and Hibernate 3.x side by 
   side in the same application.
Some of Changes made in Hibernate3.x compared with Hibernet2.x:

API Changes:

The Hibernate3 package structure is rooted at org.hibernate
 instead of net.sf.hibernate.This renaming was done to allow 
 Hibernate2 and Hibernate3 to run side by side in the same 
 application.
 Certain interfaces that have been deprecated in Hibernate3 
 were moved to the org.hibernate.classic package. 
 HibernateException and all other Hibernate exceptions are 
 changed in Hibernate3 as a unchecked runtime exceptions. 
 Compared to Hibernate2 , Hibernate3 provides the 
 ParameterizedType interface to allow better re-useability of 
 user type implementations. 
 Hibernate3.x wraps Blob and Clob instances, to allow classes 
 with a property of type Blob or Clob to be detached,serialized, 
 deserialized, and passed to merge(). Hibernate2.x not 
 supported this feature.
Metadata Changes :

In Hibernate2.x it is best practice to map almost all classes and collections using lazy="true",that is in Hibernate3.x the default feature. In hibernate2.x applications will need to explicitly specify 
lazy="false" on all non-lazy class and collection mappings. 
In hibernet 3.x The outer-join attribute is deprecated.Use fetch="join" and fetch="select" instead  of outer-join="true" and outer-join="false".
The  element is semi-deprecated,  and  are now preferred In hibernate3.x. 
       is preferred to .
       is preferred to . 
DTD reference in hbm XML files is changed in Hibernate 3.x when compared to Hibernate2.x.

Query Language Changes :

Hibernate3 comes with a brand-new, ANTLR-based
 HQL/SQL query translator. However, the Hibernate 2.1 query
 parser is still available.
 The query parser may be selected by setting the Hibernate
 property  hibernate.query.factory_class.